# How to export only the selected part of my Numbers file to PDF?

Tags: macos, mac, numbers, high-sierra, iwork

I have a **Numbers** file which has a lot of elements that when I want to export it to PDF it becomes 12 pages of A4 size. All I want is selecting part of it and exporting only that part to PDF. Is it possible?

If yes, how? please help me.

**By the way, I am using Numbers 4.3(5046)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Numbers does not have a Set Print Area option in the way that MS Excel does.

It's not clear from your question how your elements are organised, but below are three options that may be useful.

**Printing only a single sheet/tab**

If what you want is on a single sheet, then you can:

1. Go to File > Print
2. In the Print Setup window make sure you only have *This Sheet* selected instead of *All Sheets*
3. Now print to PDF

**Using Preview to create your PDF from a selected area**

Another option is to use Preview to do this for you:

1. In Numbers, select the area you want on your PDF (Hint: You can use the <kbd>command</kbd> key to select multiple elements in different parts of the sheet)
2. Now copy the selected area with <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
3. Open the Preview app
4. Go to File > New From Clipboard
5. Once the file appears, print it to PDF

**Export to Excel first**

If you happen to have access to Excel, then you could:

1. Export your Numbers spreadsheet to Excel
2. Open it in Excel
3. In Excel select the elements you want to print (Hint: You can use the <kbd>command</kbd> key to select multiple elements in different parts of the sheet)
4. Go to File > Print Area > Set Print Area
5. Now print to PDF